# Какими способами может отследить, что один и тот же человек сидит с разных профилей?

Tags: веб-программирование

В общем, есть один сайт, где я провинился в свое время и словил бан.

Но при создании нового аккаунта, меня банят через какое-то время. 
Собственно, вопрос, а какие существуют способы установить мою связь с прошлыми профилями?

Даже пробовал через VPN сидеть и все равно ловлю бан.

Далее думал, что какие-то куки следят за мной и я их тоже пробовал грохать перед новой регистрацией.

Все равно бан...

На сколько я знаю, информацию о железе браузеры получить не могут.

Comment: Либо IP-адрес, либо куки. Некоторые сайты не дают выходить через VPN. Почистите ВСЮ историю браузера и ВСЕ куки и смените IP-адрес. Попробуйте сменить браузер.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 а железо никак нельзя определить через браузер? Или например писать и читать кукки в какой-то левый домен, что бы они пережили удаление кук по конкретному сайту?

Comment: [а железо никак нельзя определить через браузер?] Производители браузеров клянутся и божатся что железо никак нельзя определить через браузер. А там кто их знает. Можно определить по косвенным признакам - например на стороне сервера можно определить разрешение монитора. Чтобы совсем оборвать все концы попробуйте зайти на этот сайт не с десктопа, а с телефона или планшета через GPRS. Этим Вы сразу измените все, и IP-адрес, и платформу, и все признаки железа.

Comment: Еще злые языки утверждают, что сервер может закинуть клиенту вирус через дырки в защите. Может Вам они с сайте закинули вирус и по этому вирусу они Вас и определяют.